# Time complexity, binary (search) tree

Tags: performance, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

assume I have a complete binary tree up-to a certain depth *d*. What would the time complexity be to traverse (pre-order traversal) this tree.

I am confused because I know that the amount of nodes in the tree is 2^d, so therefore the time complexity would be `BigO(2^d)` ? because the tree is growing exponentially.

But, upon research on the internet, Everyone states that's traversal is `BigO(n)` where n is the number of elements (which would be `2^d` in this case), not `BigO(2^d)`, what am I missing?

thanks

Comment: n = 2^d. There is no question here.

Comment: if n = 2^d, then I can say either BigO(n) or BigO(2^d). if n is 2^d?

Comment: it is customary to use n. The problem size is expressed in terms of n, and so is the complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

n is defined as the number of nodes.

2^d is only the number of nodes when every possible node at that depth is full

ie.

```
     o
   /   \
  o     o
 / \   
o   o
```

only has 5 nodes when 2^d is 8

A complete binary tree has every node filled except for last row and all of the nodes are filled to the left. You can find the definition on wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees

Comment: my question is, if its a complete tree, I.e. totally full

Comment: This is correct, except the number of nodes if the last row is full is 2^d - 1. It's worth noting also that since 2^(d-1) <= n <= 2^d - 1, it follows that O(n) = O(2^d).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can express the time complexity as O(2^d), that's pretty useless as it's not something that you can use to compare it to the time complexity of any other collection.

Expressing the time complexity as O(n) is on the other hand very useful. It tells you exactly how the collection reacts when you increase the number of items, without having to know exactly how the collection is implement, and you can compare it to the time complexity of other collections.

Comment: so what your saying is, effectively it doesn't matter which one I pick. but bigO(n) is more intuitive.

Comment: dont really understand why O(2^d) is unless, is this because the bound is so high?

Comment: @dgamma3: It's pretty useless because you have to know how the tree is implemented, otherwise it tells you nothing about how the collection reacts when you add more items to it.